# How to disable RSpec2 UTF-8 and HTML characters escaping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

WIth ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3 on Mac OS I always got "&#...;" characters in ERB template output running rspec 2.4 controllers tests (with integrate_views).

Besides "&" character and Cyrillic characters are always escaped, even using **<%= raw '...'** or **html_safe** methods.

Can anybody give a clue - what's going on here?

Comment: I believe I'm up against something similar myself. @Mirko, I'm not sure @Aristofun is talking about using the console. If his/her problem is similar to mine, the output appears in rendered/output files. (In my case it's inside a `text.erb` file which is used as an ActionMailer view.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean console/terminal output?

Try editing you `~/.profile` file and pasting this line:

```
export LANG=sr_YU.UTF-8
```

You can find listing of all available locales [here](http://manual.cream.org/index.cgi/usr/share/man/man3/DateTime%3a%3aLocaleCatalog.3pm).
Replace `sr_YU` with your own cyrillic locale.